# Как очистить прикреплённый файл html

Tags: javascript, html

Такая ситуация :
В форме есть "прикрепить геологию"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда нажимаем на "прикрепить геологию",то должны выбрать файл.Значит выбрали файл и происходит это :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Бывает "Прикреплено файлов: 1"

Как сделать так,чтобы был крестик рядом и при нажатии на него можно было бы очистить выбранный файл,чтобы снова стало "прикрепить геологию"

[вот тут html этой формы](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/L_JvJg_C0KY_jg)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого по нажатию на крестик (onclick="clearinput()")

```
function clearinput(){
     document.getElementById("Id input file").value='';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Очистить значение input`а

```js
$('#input__file').change(function(){
  if($('#input__file').val() != 'undefined'){
    $('body').append('<div class="clear">X</div>');
  }
})

$(document).on('click', '.clear', function(){
  $('#input__file').val('');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="input__file" />
```

Comment: Не плохо не плохо,ты опередил меня,но знай,хоть я и програл эту битву на скорость,но война еще не проиграна

Comment: А можно ли сделать так,чтобы это крестик появлялся когда выбрал файл?

Comment: @АндрейНикитин дополнил код в ответе